# What hand tools would I need to remove a portion of this stone wall?

Tags: walls, stone

https://i.ibb.co/3skNFMR/IMG-8506.jpg

Just bought a house and need to remove a portion of this stone wall with lime mortar.

I’m thinking cold chisel and lump hammer?

[image: walll]

Comment: surgically remove or break/destroy

Comment: Reason for remove?  Wall seems in decent shape, so the reason to remove a part might help.

Comment: @crip659 bought a house without vehicle access and it came with planning for a drive. We need to move some stones to accommodate.

Comment: If you already have an air compressor, I would recommend a cheap (<$20) pneumatic chisels from harbor fright, or from anywhere really. They save a ton of arm soreness on bigger jobs like you have.

Comment: It might be that the bare ends need to be finished in some way to prevent rapid decay. If the stone has some value, maybe there is someone nearby who is skilled at building stone walls and would do a good job for you and you'd get a reduced rate by letting them take the old stones away. Will you need a gate to keep farm animals out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is an iron bar and leverage. For example, [this one](https://www.harborfreight.com/17-lb-digging-bar-with-tamper-93612.html) goes for $30. Just wedge the flat end between two layers, and pry off. The mortar is unlikely to be gluing the stones together, so they'll just come right off. I seriously doubt you will need a demo hammer, as the mortar is most likely loose, and you are not going to be breaking stones with a demo hammer (see below for that.)

Once the stones are on the ground, the fun starts. Use either a hand-truck (dolly) to move them, or lean a wheelbarrow on its side, drag one stone into the wheelbarrow, then push the wheelbarrow upright. Carry away and repeat.

If by chance you find a stone that is too large to carry with these methods, then you'll have to drill a series of holes and [use wedges to split it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0977H9MFQ). Drilling the holes takes 95% of the time, splitting the stones just a few minutes.

If you have never done this before, pace yourself and don't try to do too much at once.

In your question you mention that a driveway is planned. Whomever is cutting the driveway will most likely bring a loader, even if just to spread the crushed rock and gravel. They can then easily use the loader and/or mini excavator to move the stones.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a heavy duty extension cord, say 12 gauge wire, rent an electric "[demo hammer](https://www.cpooutlets.com/factory-reconditioned-bosch-11335k-rt-35-lb.-breaker-hammer-jack/bshr11335k-rt.html?ref=pla&utm_term=go_cmp-20295759023_adg-_ad-__dev-c_ext-_prd-bshr11335k-rt_mca-10260152_sig-Cj0KCQjw1OmoBhDXARIsAAAYGSH91AuYyCG-7aDVridKwcyv6xr0kivN-6usWk5xk6hkTaUQEB-lGh4aAiEgEALw_wcB&utm_source=google&ref=gg-pla&utm_id=go_cmp-20295759023_adg-_ad-__dev-c_ext-_prd-bshr11335k-rt_sig-Cj0KCQjw1OmoBhDXARIsAAAYGSH91AuYyCG-7aDVridKwcyv6xr0kivN-6usWk5xk6hkTaUQEB-lGh4aAiEgEALw_wcB&utm_medium=pla&utm_campaign=cpo_gg_pla_cpo_shop_bosch_pmax&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1OmoBhDXARIsAAAYGSH91AuYyCG-7aDVridKwcyv6xr0kivN-6usWk5xk6hkTaUQEB-lGh4aAiEgEALw_wcB)" from the local rental company. Get the largest hand held they have for rent.

It should make pretty fast work of that. It won't be easy, the stones are incredibly heavy. If you just concentrate on separating the stones at the joints, in the reverse order they were laid, they should pop out readily. If you go for breaking the stones into smaller pieces, well, that may be another story.

If you have a tractor with a front bucket, would really be handy for the moving of the stone as it comes loose.